# Cordova project in Visual Studio fails to build on Android: cannot find com.android.support:support-v4

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

When I try to build a Cordova project for Android in Visual Studio 2017 that uses the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner plugin, I get the following error:

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:+ as no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Searched in the following locations:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  file:/C:/Users/ischemm/Git/engage-cordova-app/engage-cordova-app/platforms/android/libs/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Required by:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  :android:unspecified
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager).

First, change the directory to Visual Studio's install directory for the Android SDK, which is usually:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\{version}
```

(Note that C:\ProgramData is a hidden folder, so you'll need to change the File Explorer settings to make hidden folders visible.)

Then uninstall and reinstall the Android Support Repository, listed under Extras.